# How can I use macrubyc under Mac OSX Lion?

Tags: ruby, gcc, macruby, macrubyc

I'm wondering if anyone of you has used `macrubyc` on Lion.

My problem is, that `macrubyc` depends on gcc-compiler. Lion is shipped without gcc.
Is it possible to use `macrubyc` with the shipped llvm-compiler?

Are there other alternatives to create a binary from my ruby-script.
As it seems, `macruby` does not support the compilation of all required gems, is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know what exactly is the problem. I'm using the [Mac Ruby Installer](https://github.com/downloads/MacRuby/MacRuby/MacRuby%200.12.zip) which works fine for me on Mountain Lion.

I you need gcc for Lion+ you may use the installer [Kenneth Reitz's custom gcc installer](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer/).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'd actually like to avoid the gcc installation. But it will do, if there is no other solution.